# como solventar el error Function name must be a string (0)

Tags: php

estoy utilizando el framework KUMBIAPHP, resulta que en mi equipo lugar estoy utilizando la version de PHP 5.6 y el hosting donde estoy subiendo el proyecto utiliza PHP 7.0 y ahora el proyecto me arroja un error Function name must be a string (0), la linea donde esta dando error esta comentada al lado a continuacion el codigo:

```
public static function dbSelect($field, $show = NULL, $data = NULL, $blank = 'Seleccione', $attrs = NULL, $value = NULL)
{
    if (is_array($attrs)) {
        $attrs = Tag::getAttrs($attrs);
    }

    // Obtiene name, id y value (solo para autoload) para el campo y los carga en el scope
    list($id, $name, $value) = self::getFieldData($field, $value);

    // Si no se envía un campo por defecto, no se crea el tag option
    if ($blank != NULL) {
        $options = '<option value="">' . htmlspecialchars($blank, ENT_COMPAT, APP_CHARSET) . '</option>';
    } else {
        $options = '';
    }

    //por defecto el modelo de modelo(_id)
    if ($data === NULL) {
        $model_asoc = explode('.', $field, 2);
        $model_asoc = substr(end($model_asoc), 0, -3); //se elimina el _id
        $model_asoc = Load::model($model_asoc);
        $pk = $model_asoc->primary_key[0];

        if (!$show) {
            //por defecto el primer campo no pk
            $show = $model_asoc->non_primary[0];
        }

        $data = $model_asoc->find("columns: $pk,$show", "order: $show asc"); //mejor usar array
    } else {
        $model_asoc = Load::model($data[0]);
        $pk = $model_asoc->primary_key[0];

        // Verifica si existe el parámetro
        if (isset($data[2])) {
            $data = $model_asoc->$data[1]($data[2]); //ERROR EN ESTA LINEA
        } else {
            $data = $model_asoc->$data[1](); //ERROR EN ESTA LINEA TAMBIEN
        }
    }
```

espero me puedan ayudar como resolver este detalle.

Comment: Prueba con `$model_asoc->{$data[1]}`

Comment: lo que comenta sal debería funcionar. Por otro lado solo decir que hay un buen trecho de cambios entre la version5 y la 7... seguramente lo mejor sería instalarte php7 en tu local y usarlo para desarrollar sitios que se van a desplegar en php7... sino siempre encontrarás problemas que no ves en tu local

Comment: gracias por comentar, de esa manera no sale el error pero no funciona, ya que no carga la etiqueta con la data, esa función lo que hace es crear una etiqueta HTML <select> con los datos de una tabla de la base de datos, no sale el error, pero crea el select vacío.